# PHP using Woocommerce wcs_user_has_subscription function with specific user_id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm getting crazy on this.

I'm making a wordpress plugin and I need to use wcs_user_has_subscription on every user to get the list of every user having this subscription.

Seem's pretty simple, but I can't make the function work when I give a specific user_id.

Everything work fine when I call the function like this :

```
$has_sub = wcs_user_has_subscription('', 4743, 'active');
```

but when I do something like this :

```
$subscribers = get_users('role=subscriber');
foreach ( $subscribers as $user ) {
    $has_sub = wcs_user_has_subscription($user->id, 4743, 'active');
}
```

I get this error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_order() on null in /path/to/woocommerce-subscriptions/wcs-functions.php on line 81
```

Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: As mentioned @Benoti, hook your function to `init` action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You plugin loads get_order() even the woocommerce librairies aren't already load.

Comment: Thanks, I was hooked on "plugins loaded" witch say : This hook is called once any activated plugins have been loaded.

Still I wonder why it was working fine without any ID :(